# nuxt-link passing a config variable as the query key

Tags: javascript, vue.js, environment-variables, nuxt.js

I want to pass an env config variable `process.env.config.myVar` to my nuxt-link, something like:

```
:to="{
  name: 'search-page',
  query: {
    process.env.config.myVar: { query: `${searchValue}` }
  }
}"
```

So far I have tried this:

```
:to="{
  name: 'search-page',
  query: {
    ['process.env.config.myVar']: { query: `${searchValue}` }
  }
}"
```

But it prints the entire `process.env.config.myVar` as the parameter. Also tried to assign it to a data variable like: `myVar= process.env.config.myVar` and then pass it to nuxt-link:

```
:to="{
  name: 'search-page',
  query: {
    myVar: { query: `${searchValue}` }
  }
}"
```

But it prints `myvar` as the parameter. How can I pass that environmental variable to my nuxt-link?

Comment: Don't use quotes: `[process.env.config.myVar]`

Comment: it gives me an error saying "Cannot read property 'env' of undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use quotes when you want to use a javascript argument as an object key:

```
[process.env.config.myVar]: { query: `${searchValue}` }
```

However, you also do not have access to `process` in the `<template>` syntax of single file components in Vue. `Nuxt` utilizes the idea of a [runtimeConfig](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-runtime-config), so we can share the values directly to our `$config` object:

```
// nuxt.config.js
publicRuntimeConfig: {
  myVar: process.env.config.myVar
}
```

Now you can access the value of this in your `<template>` by using `$config.myVar`

```
:to="{
  name: 'search-page',
  query: {
    [$config.myVar]: { query: `${searchValue}` }
  }
}"
```